# After deploying precompiled C# Azure function via Kudu API might still use old code

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, azure-functions, kudu

We have written a [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) based build script that compiles our C# Azure function app, creates a .zip file from it and deploys it to Azure via the Kudu API.

After building and copying the relevant files of the app to the deploy folder, it looks like this:

```
- host.json
- Function01
    |- function.json
    |- Function01.dll
    |- Dependency.dll
- Function02
    |- function.json
    |- Function02.dll
    |- Dependency.dll
```

This is then zipped and deployed to Kudu like this:

```
- Delete `site/wwwroot` to get rid of current state
- Recreate `site/wwwroot`
- Upload created .zip file to `site/wwwroot`
```

This script works very nice for our Javascript based function apps, but for the C# one, it sometimes happens that the runtime does not pick up the newly deployed binaries but keeps using the old ones. Restarting the app does not help either. We do not encounter this behavior every time but maybe one in five cases. Does the runtime cache the binaries somewhere or do we need to change the folder where the binaries are stored?

All devs are working with VS for Mac. We don't have Windows machines around nor want to deploy from VS directly but use our Continuous Deploy pipeline via our Jenkins server.

Comment: The c# build instructions need dependencies to determine when to rebuild executables.  You do not have the correct dependencies.  When you add existing items to a project the build instructions are automatically updated.  If the object are not added to the project then you have to add manual dependency instructions to the project .

Comment: The deps are properly added in VS for Mac. Our problem is not the build. The assemblies are rebuilt correctly each and every time and they seem to get replace when we look at the time stamp of the files via the Kudu console. But the running code in Azure seems not to be the one from the currently uploaded assemblies, but from the former version.

Comment: Are the files getting closed properly?  If the files are still open in write mode you may get previous version instead of current version.  Not familiar with MAC.  Are you using Creation Date or Modified Date?

Comment: Just look in Kudu Console for signs of the odl assemblies. There is really no way it can be running the old code unless the old binaries are still there. Did you try restarting the app?

Comment: Sorry, I see you mention you tried restarting. Try also wiping out all the files, verifying that you have no functions, and then deploying again.

Comment: This is why we use the kudu api to fully delete the `site/wwwroot` before. When we download the assemblies and decompile them, they are the new version. Donna Malayeri told me on Twitter that VS puts the assemblies into the `bin` folder. Might this be something? We leave them in the associated function's folder.